# VB Code to check Windows Update says Server not available

Tags: windows, vb.net, server, updates

I wrote a tool to check the windows updates on multiple server or clients and on some servers everything is ok but on a few it gives me the System.Exeption:

```
The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable.
  at Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.CreateObject(String ProgId, String ServerName)
  at MJ_Update_Manager.MJUM_Form.Update_Checker_Background()
```

Can anyone help me? Is there something missing on the server?

```
Dim updateSession = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.Session", TMPServer) ' here is the exeption/problem

Dim updateSearcher = updateSession.CreateupdateSearcher()
Dim searchResult = updateSearcher.Search("IsInstalled=0 and Type='Software'")
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that `TMPServer` is accessible from a machine where the tool doesn't work?

Comment: Hi yes all server with this error are accessible

Comment: Have you restarted the Windows Update service? Have you used DISM to check for Windows Update database corruption? Do all the servers currently have all the same updates?

Comment: yes i tried both. Are there any requirements that the server has to fulfill?Net Framework-Version or something?

Comment: I am no expert on the matter; I simply saw that KB4034658 could be a problem in [Problem with Microsoft.Update.Session on Windows 2016](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/5b2764cd-8aff-4de7-a1ca-0d6e2e62de55/problem-with-microsoftupdatesession-on-windows-2016?forum=winserverpowershell).

Comment: maybe it is the same problem but how to fix this on windows Server 2012R2 ?